# prepend comment to comment list it belongs to

Tags: jquery

I have a page where I loop out several posts each containing a list of comments belonging to that post. On each post I also have form where you can leave a comment on that post.

I'm trying to prepend a comment to the comment list belonging to the post the comment was left on. For now it always prepends the comment to the comment list of the first post on my page.

jQuery:

```
$('.btn-comment').on("click", function (e) {
    var text = $('.comment-text').val();
    var post_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "./ajax/ajax_comment.php",
        data: { text: text, post_id: post_id }
    })
    .done(function( res ) {
        if (res.status == "success") {
            var comment = `<li class="comment-li" style="display: none;"> TEXT </li>`;

            $(".comment-ul").prepend(comment);
            $(".comment-li").first().slideDown();
        }
});
```

html:

```
<ul class="posts">

    <li class="post" data-id="1">
        <h1>POST 1</h1>
        <form action="" class="comment-form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment1" class="comment-text">
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="1" class="post_id">
            <input type="submit" data-id="1" class="btn-comment">
        </form>

        <ul class="comment-ul" data-id="1">
            <li class="comment-li">Comment 1</li>
            <li class="comment-li">Comment 2</li>
            <li class="comment-li">Comment 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="post" data-id="2">
        <h1>POST 2</h1>
        <form action="" class="comment-form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment2" class="comment-text">
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="2" class="post_id">
            <input type="submit" data-id="2" class="btn-comment">
        </form>

        <ul class="comment-ul" data-id="2">
            <li class="comment-li">Comment 1</li>
            <li class="comment-li">Comment 2</li>
            <li class="comment-li">Comment 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

All the comment handling is done with Ajax and everything works, but it's just the frontend placing of the comments that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the code handling that form post?  Presumably you could use that `post_id` value (from the hidden element or the submit button) to target the specific `ul` that you want, given its `data-id` attribute.

Comment: @David I've added the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An additional problem in your code is that you're only ever getting the first post's comment:

```
var text = $('.comment-text').val();
```

Both this problem and the one you describe are the same, though.  Operations like that will always return the *first* match.  And even when you prepend your new element (which you prepend to *all* matches), you explicitly animate the first match:

```
$(".comment-li").first().slideDown();
```

The first thing you want to do in your click handler is determine the local context of what was clicked.  It could be as simple as:

```
$('.btn-comment').on("click", function (e) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    //...
});
```

With that `id` you can specifically target the elements you want.  For example:

```
var text = $('li[data-id="' + id + '"]').find('.comment-text').val();
```

and:

```
$('li[data-id="' + id + '"]').find(".comment-ul").prepend(comment);
$('li[data-id="' + id + '"]').find(".comment-li").first().slideDown();
```

---

Conversely, without using the `id` (or for future readers who may not have that in their markup), you can capture the clicked element and traverse the DOM from the context of that element.  Something like this:

```
var element = $(this);
var text = element.closest('li.post').find('.comment-text').val();
```

and in the callback:

```
element.closest('li.post').find(".comment-ul").prepend(comment);
element.closest('li.post').find(".comment-li").first().slideDown();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're not preserving any relationship between the clicked button and the comments list relating to it - instead, you're targeting ALL comment lists, because your selector is `.comment-ul`, with no further specificity.

```
$('.btn-comment').on("click", function (e) {
    var
    text = $(this).siblings('.comment-text').val(),
    post_id = $(this).attr('data-id'),
    ul = $(this).closest('.post').find('.comment-ul'); //<-- grab this post's comments list

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "./ajax/ajax_comment.php",
        data: { text: text, post_id: post_id }
    })
    .done(function( res ) {
        if (res.status == "success") {
            var comment = `<li class="comment-li" style="display: none;"> TEXT </li>`;

            ul.prepend(comment).slideDown(); //<-- target just our UL, not all
        }
});
```

The key line is where we define `ul`. We have to map from the clicked button to the corresponding comments list. The route, looking at your HTML, is out and up to the ancestor `.post` element, then back in and down to the descendant `.comment-ul` element.

Comment: Now it does slide down a comment at the right place! The only thing is that the comment-text still isn't the comment from the selected input. It takes the comment-text from the first post.

Comment: I didn't spot that problem. Now updated. The basic rule is: always keep things contextual (to the event trigger) in event callbacks. Generalised selectors in event callbacks lose specificity with the element that triggered the event.

Comment: Thanks @Utkanos! :)

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer helped you, please upvote it and mark the answer as accepted :)